# AWS EKS how can the container also inherit the host's /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: amazon-eks, coredns

Is there a way to set automatically that any new containers query from the instance's host /etc/resolv.conf but it also requires to be able to query the cluster locally too.
What i tried is dhcp options set and it does work for instances and docker containers but does not work for eks clusters.

The goal is really to have the containers within the eks cluster have additional nameservers without manual configuration because the eks cluster's admin is managed by a vendor.

Currently all containers have this in /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.100.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local ca-central-1.compute.internal
options ndots:5

- what are other options to add another nameserver entry.
- i know setting the coredns config map is one method but we dont' have admin access. Any other solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating private dns hosts.